# PowerShell convert string to variable

Tags: arrays, string, powershell, variables

In PowerShell I'm working on a script and can't solve this:

```
$GROUPA = 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'
$GROUPB = 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H'

$SELECT = 'GROUPA'

write-output $$SELECT (or something)
```

I have a view arrays, and than a script thats output one of the array names. And I want to output that array, but can't find how to do that with powershell.

Comment: Why is everyone so hell-bent on trying to define variables on the fly? Please take a step back and describe the actual problem you're trying to solve instead of what you perceive as the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Your `$SELECT` is just a *string*, instead you probably want to assign it to the  `$GROUPA` variable:

```
$SELECT = $GROUPA    
write-output $SELECT
```

Or, if you wan't a to *resolve*  a variable using a string, use the `Get-Variable` cmdlet:

```
$SELECT = Get-Variable 'GROUPA'
```

Comment: yes, but how? because $SELECT = $+'GROUPA' output $GROUPA

Comment: If you just write `$SELECT` it will output the array.

Comment: $SELECT2 = Get-Variable $SELECT is working thank you

Comment: Your welcome. Ansgar is write, you should think about whether this is the right approach for your solution. However, please consider to accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you (even if it's old topic)

```
$A=1
$B=2
$C=3
$D=4
$E=11
$F=12
$G=13
$H=14
$GROUPA = 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'
$GROUPB = 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H'
$SELECT=$GROUPB
$myval1 = (Get-Variable $SELECT[0]).Value
$myval2 = (Get-Variable $SELECT[1]).Value
$myval3 = (Get-Variable $SELECT[2]).Value
$myval4 = (Get-Variable $SELECT[3]).Value
```